# Creating xml file with mysql and php. Would like to add a custom row

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Not sure how to accomplish this task.

I create a xml file from a mysql database with php.

```
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  
// ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE  
$node = $dom->createElement("marker");  
$newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
$newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
$newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
$newnode->setAttribute("title",$row['title']);
$newnode->setAttribute("icon", $row['icon']);
$newnode->setAttribute("rink", $row['rink']);

}
```

How would I add a column combining 2 rows, for example.

```
$newnode->setAttribute("custom", $row['rink']<br>$row['rinksize']);
```

setAttribute does not like more then 2 argument...

Thanks

~edit~

For example I get this result.

```
<marker lng="-71.062228" lat="42.366303" title="Boston Bruins" icon="red" rink="TD Garden"/>
```

I would like this.

```
<marker lng="-71.062228" lat="42.366303" title="Boston Bruins" icon="red" rink="TD Garden" custom="TD Garden<br>20000"/>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want for the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, you need to concatenate the strings. You probably want to use this:
`$newnode->setAttribute("custom", $row['rink'] . '<br>' . $row['rinksize']);`

The `.` operator will combine two strings together. Also, just a note: `<br>` should probably be `<br />` for it to be *more* valid.